# yii1 date-picker storing values as 000-00-00 in database

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, yii, datepicker

I am tring to use date picker in an form  but after submitting, the value is stored as **000-00-00** in database and while Viewing the details after submitting the form the **minDate** value is displayed .

the same date picker is working fine in other form ,
I am trying to re-use the date picker

**file.js**

```
function userDetailsEventHandlers() {

$('.date-picker').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',
        yearRange: '1900:1998',
        minDate: '01-January-1900',
        maxDate: '31-December-1998',
    });
}
```

**form.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'DOB'); ?>
     <?php echo $form->textField($model,'DOB', array('class' => 'form-control date-picker')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'DOB'); ?>
</div>
```

**Model class :**

```
protected function afterFind() {

       if (!empty($this->DOB)) {
            $this->DOB = date('d-F-Y', strtotime($this->DOB));
        }
        return parent::afterFind();
    }
```

The datatype in database : datetime (I also tried with date).
The datatype in other form where datepicker is used is datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally used CJuiDatePicker, :P

```
<div class="form-group">
                                 <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'DOB'); ?>
                                 <?php
                                    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
                                        'model'     => $model,
                                        'attribute' => 'DOB',
                                        'language'=> 'en',


                                        'name'=>'datepicker-month-year-menu',
                                         //'flat'=>true,//remove to hide
                                        'options'=>array(
                                            'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
                                            'showAnim'=>'slide',//'slide','fold','slideDown','fadeIn','blind','bounce','clip','drop'
                                            'changeMonth'=>true,
                                            'changeYear'=>true,
                                            'yearRange'=>'1900:1998',
                                           // 'minDate' => '2000-01-01',      // minimum date
                                           // 'maxDate' => '2099-12-31',      // maximum date
                                        ),
                                        'htmlOptions'=>array(
                                            'class' => 'form-control',
                                            'style'=>''
                                        ),
                                    ));
                                    ?>

                                     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yyyy', <------------ Make this changes
        yearRange: '1900:1998',
        minDate: '01-01-1900',  <------------ Make this changes
        maxDate: '31-12-1998',
    });
}
```

As you specified dateformat as 'dd-MM-yy' need to transfer minDate and maxDate in same format.
Also make sure which format is passing at server side.if it is other than `yyyy-MM-dd` You need to manually convert that string content into date using `STR_TO_DATE()`.
Just try above code.
Hope this will helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with date format, as your date picker is using date format:

```
'01-January-1900'
 // which is different then 'Y-m-d'
```

but the default format for date column is `'Y-m-d'`, and if your data is not in proper format then it will insert `000-00-00`. So change your date to `'Y-m-d'` and try again.